# How to make a new build for "vue-form-generator" plugin

Tags: vue.js, build, components

A newbie question here.

I'm new to Vue.js and want to use the "vue-form-generator" plugin - https://github.com/vue-generators/vue-form-generator

I want to make a small change to one of its components. But in order to see the change, as I understand I  need to make a new build and will have a fresh 'dist' folder.
I'm having a hard time trying to use Vue Cli and 'npm run build' in order to compile the changes.

Any one can point me in the right direction for what steps should I follow in order to do that ?

Many thanks.

Comment: This is a vendor package. You cannot use `vue-cli` to re-bundle the vendor package. You need to fork that github repository, make your change, use `npm run bundle:core` within that repository, then push it to your github. Once done, update your `package.json` in your `vue` project and add a `repository` object with `type` of `git` and a `url` property pointing to the url of the fork you created.

Comment: Thank you @Ohgodwhy